Call Edge Function from Database Trigger
I am using supabase and I try to implement some warning functionality. I want to send an E-Mail when a value drops under a specific value.
I know about database triggers but I am not sure about two things.

How can I check if the value is dropping below the threshold the first time? Is there a chance to get the before and after value of a change in a table row?
Can I call an Edge Function from the trigger or from a database function that is called from the trigger where I can send the E-Mail?


Your design is possible.
About point 1:
postgres trigger-functions can see the OLD and NEW value as special variables. See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html
They may be null though, depending on the operation (insert doesn't have a OLD, delete has no NEW). You can also access the operation that triggered your trigger using TG_OP, see here: PostgreSQL: Checking for NEW and OLD in a function for a trigger
About point 2:
Postgres-triggers can make http-requests with the pg_net-extension, which you can use to trigger your edge-function with the right data. It's a bit bare-bones, but it works. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pg_net

Not sure if that is really what you want to do though - if 10 values fall below thresholds in short succession, do you want to send 10 emails, or do you want to aggregate the warnings into one report? Aggregating into one would be hard with this design. But I don't know your requirements.

Awesome! Thanks you so much for this information. I only have one or two thresholds for each account anyways. So I want to send the email every time it falls below a threshold. This will not happen that often.

This can be achieved with the WebHooks functionality provided by supabase.
It allows you to react to changes in the database and then make a http request based on that. This could be used to trigger a function on some running web server, or in your case to run an edge function.
Here is an example of how to trigger edge functions using http requests.
Then you only need to write and edge function that sends the e-mail.
Under the hood it actually uses Postgres triggers and pg_net, but it is probably easier to implement the logic using this abstraction rather than manually using those components. In other words, what ends up happening is quite similar to the previous answer.

This answer is better than mine. From the doc: "Database Webhooks are just a convenience wrapper around triggers using the pg_net extension". So the extension is doing what I proposed to do, except with an official library and not homegrown code.
